# mamp phpmyadmin error script to import database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

This is my error:

> Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit the same file and import will resume

I have problems importing a database, I have already made all the configurations that I show here

```
max_execution_time = 3000000 
max_input_time = 60000000000000
memory_limit = 1280000000000000000000M
post_max_size = 4096456M
upload_max_filesize = 40964564M
max_file_uploads = 200

$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

Comment: You really should not use phpmyadmin to import a large dump file into mysql. It was not designed for this. Use the command line or a desktop client for such operations.

Answer (score 0):

As Shadow mentioned, phpMyAdmin is not the most appropriate tool when importing any file larger than a few megabytes. It would be better to use the command line. Here's how you can do it:

0. Open Terminal
1. Go to the directory where the `.sql` file that you want to import is, for example: `cd ~/Downloads`
2. Import the file into a waiting database:

```
mysql -u admin -p {databasename} < data_to_import.sql
```

When you press <kbd>Return</kbd>, you'll be prompted for the password.

Be sure to change `admin` to the proper account name, `{databasename}` to the proper database that will receive the data, and `data_to_import.sql` to the actual file that you want to use.